# Jquery Ajax Return

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I try to load a local XML File with Jquery, with this function:

```
function initXML()
{
  var returnVal;
  $.ajax({
    url: 'js/xml/Menue.xml',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        returnVal = data;
    },
    error: loadfail
   });
  return returnVal;
 }
```

and test the return value with

```
alert(initXML());
```

The first alertBox has a value, but the second alertBox is empty.
What is wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You won't get any data on this `alert(initXML())` because the function `initXml` has an asynchronous request, at the time the alert fires, the function `initXML` returns `undefined`. You will alert something for the `alert(data)` though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the value of `returnVal` in an alert only after the async request is done, add this to your AJAX settings:

```
 complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
alert(returnVal);    
}
```

Also, my two side notes:

- Use `console.log()` instead of `alert` if you are debugging. There are few things more embarassing than alerts that pop up in production code.
- Note sure which jQuery version you're coding against, but as of jQuery 1.8, `success`, `error`, and `complete` have been deprecated (see https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)